# Clipping on SVG with 'mousemove' and mouse position alternative for mobile

Tags: javascript, svg, mobile

The idea is there is a black and white picture, and on 'mousemove' using SVG clipping the image "gain colour" (following my mouse movement). I do this by getting the mouse coordinates and clipping the black and white picture with the coloured version of it. It works perfectly on desktop with every browser.

```
var clientX = 0;
var clientY = 0;

getCoordinates = function(event) {
  clientX = event.clientX;
  clientY = event.clientY;
};

updateRect = function() {
  creative.dom.rect.setAttribute('x', clientX);
  creative.dom.rect.setAttribute('y', clientY);
};

clipThroughImage = function() {
  updateRect();
};

creative.dom.imageBw.addEventListener('mousemove', getCoordinates);
creative.dom.imageBw.addEventListener('mousemove', clipThroughImage);
```

On mobile, however, the clipping only "works" (when I keep 'mousemove') by tapping. Instead of the colour following my finger movement (like it does with the mouse), it just instantly goes there when I tap.

I tried using 'touchmove' but then it doesn't work at all, it just clips the entire coloured image and that's it.

What do I need to change to get the same results on mobile?

Answer (score 0):

Made it work with the following:

```
var allowSwipe = true;

getCoordinates = function(event) {

  if (!allowSwipe) return; 
  allowSwipe = false;

  setTimeout(function() {
    allowSwipe = true;
  }, 10);

  clientX = (event.clientX || event.touches[0].clientX);
  clientY = (event.clientY || event.touches[0].clientY);

  clipThroughImage();
};

creative.dom.imageBw.addEventListener('touchmove', getCoordinates);
creative.dom.imageBw.addEventListener('mousemove', getCoordinates);
```

And the rest of the code was still the same.